# C++11 random number generator UIntType contradiction

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Section 26.5.1.1 paragraph 1 of the C++11 standard (N3242) says:

> Throughout this subclause 26.5, the effect of instantiating a template:
>
> [...]
>
> f) that has a template type parameter named `UIntType` is 
>   undefined unless the corresponding template
>   argument is cv-unqualified and is one of `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`.

And it defines the linear congruential generator in 26.5.3.1. The definition of the class starts like this:

```
template<class UIntType, UIntType a, UIntType c, UIntType m>
class linear_congruential_engine
```

`minstd_rand0` seems to violate this restriction:

```
typedef linear_congruential_engine<uint_fast32_t, 16807, 0, 2147483647>
    minstd_rand0;
```

As it uses uint_fast32_t (which isn't guaranteed to be one of `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`) in `minstd_rand0` for a template parameter named `UIntType`, it appears to have undefined effect to `#include <random>`, or at least to use `minstd_rand0`. This problem applies to other predefined RNGs as well, and it does not appear to be fixed in C++14.

My questions are:

- Is this really a contradiction (or rather an extreme amount of undefined behaviour), or have I missed something?
- Has this been mentioned in a defect report?

**Edit:** I have noticed that [this](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#2326) defect report seems to be related to this problem.

Comment: Well, the *Required behavior* clause that immediately follows it arguably necessarily requires using such a thing to be well-defined. Regardless, is there an actual system in which `uint_fast32_t` is *not* one of those types?

Comment: @T.C. I suppose it might, but I think that it only requires the 10000th invocation to be correct. The 10001th invocation could still cause a problem (or for that matter, an engine that wasn't default constructed).

Comment: @T.C. MSVC might define `uint_fast32_t` using their `unsigned __int32` type (I don't know as I don't use MSVC). I agree that this question is academic though.

Comment: Isn't that just a synonym for a built-in, not its own type? Anyway, for a compiler with no extended integer types (and last time I checked, neither GCC nor Clang nor MSVC have them), `uint_fast32_t` must be a built-in type.

Comment: @T.C. avr-gcc (GCC for AVR microcontrollers, which are 8 bit microcontrollers made by atmel) has __uint24 and __int24 which are not one of `short`, `int`, etc. Unfortunately this is an undocumented feature, but this page on the gcc wiki mentions it: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Types

Comment: "extended integer type" is a standard term-of-art. GCC has `__int128`, for example, but that isn't an extended integer type.

Comment: @T.C. True, but it isn't one of `short`, `int`, etc. either. Sorry I misunderstood what you meant by built-in type. I shouldn't have argued with you. But no standard library is actually going to have this problem (as they would make an implementation of `linear_congruential_engine` that works with `uint_fast32_t`) anyway, so this is more about a contradiction in the standard than about any practical problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Per section 18.4.1, `uint_fast32_t` Has to be an alias to an unsigned integer type. While the only unsigned integer types in C++ are unsigned char, short, int, long, long, long (3.9.1) So the only scenario that the section you mentioned can be a contradiction is that char is somehow 32-bits or wider and and uint_fast32_t is defined to an alias to unsigned char.

Answer (score 1):

uint_fast32_t is specified to be the fastest unsigned integer type with width of at least 32 bits.

In C++ type system, both character and integer types are integral types, but character types are not integer types (nor vice-versa).

Finally, unsigned integer types are exactly the ones enumerated for random generators.

My conclusion is that using uint_fast32_t complies with the standard (unless I missed some part of the standard where it is specifically allowed for uint_fast32_t to be a nonstsndard type, or for the definition of integer type to include nonstandard types).

However, I believe the spec should be fixed to try to avoid ambiguous interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but my answer is that yes it is a defect, if you are correct that `uint_fast32_t` need not be one of those types according to the standard.

The proposal in the NAD issue 2326 you referenced would appear to also resolve this defect.